# Gmail logout functionality in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in selenium webdrive and try to make a code for gmail login and logout but not able to logout via "Id", it would be helpful for me if anyone suggest that how to logout it. Below are the code which I did please check and suggest:

```
public class seleniumExample {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement element, element1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Intialize chrome driver
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        element.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
        element1.sendKeys("xyz");
        element.submit();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbi4m1")).click(); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the error you get and at what line?

Comment: If your learning, google is not the right place to start with,it produces dynamic ids and page is complex

Comment: @Amith: I appreciate with your words and check the below points in which you are talking about chrome console, but friendly speaking i am not understand yet how can we get the Id or method from that i can open that popup in gmail which contains logout button.

Or can you please suggest from where i can learn it exactly?

Comment: you can use "inspect element" through your browser to see the html code for a particular element, using this you can experiment with different selectors or xpaths to locate it

Answer (score 4):

The following id :`gbi4m1` does not point to anything. This is causing your test case to fail. As i said before google is not a right place to learn selenium, the page is complex and dynamic id's are hard to deal with if you are beginner.

Normally in browsers you can use development tools to check if a selector can be used to locate an element. So before you actually use a particular selector in your code, you can verify if it works. This will save a lot of time.

One more advantage of using this would be to check the **uniqueness** of a selector. If there are multiple elements with the same selector,`findElement()` returns the first one. In this 
case the selector would be valid but it won't be unique, which in turn causes your test case to fail.

If a selector is unique, console displays only one element.

Let me explain with a simple example **:**

To click on **Ask Question** button on the top right of this page, following selector would work.

```
css = #nav-askquestion
```

So now you can confirm this by using the dev tools of your browser.

Just type `$('selector_to_check')` on the console and it displays all elements related with this selector.

I have used Chrome :

[image]

If the selector entered is invalid,an empty array is displayed.

Comment: and `$x` for XPath queries, +1.

Comment: Personally, I find Firefox with Firebug and Firepath plugins to be more useful and user friendly then using the console to try xpath/css

Answer (score 0):

First, id that you are taking doesn't exists. So that won't work. Secondly, once you correctly identify the logout button,it would be a bit more easy for us to identify exact nature of your  problem

Comment: For logout button id is correct, main thing which I want to know that how can I open that popup which contains "Logout" button, so that I give the click event on logout button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where did you get  "gbi4m1"? anyhow why not use By.className

```
driver.findElement(By.className("gb_O")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

Seems to work for me

Comment: As I apply this line 
"driver.findElement(By.className("gb_Q gbii")).click();"
for opening a popup in which gmail contains a logout button but its not showing by this class name and reproduce the below cause in console:

The given selector gb_Q gbii is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: you can't have spaces in there even if the code reads "gb_O gbii" because like the error states compound class names are not permitted. note is an "O" instead of a Q. thats why in my code I just use "gb_O" to select the class and is enough for webdriver to find the logout button

Answer (score 0):

use cssSelector, Following code work for me

1. **//Click on the profile image present in the right top corner
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.gb_3a.gbii")).click();
   //Click on 'Sign Out' button
   driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click(); //Close the browser
   window driver.close();**

---

Answer (score 0):

this is awesome code for gmail logout in selenium webdriver

```
driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a/span"))
        .click();
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code is working for me :-

```
driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a/span"))
        .click();
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

I used xpath for finding the account icon and it is working fine for me.

Comment: That Xpath looks pretty brittle to me and not a particularly good example of how to use and create xpath for automation

Comment: @RobbieWareham -  I usually dont recommend using xpath. But in this particular example the xpath looks pretty stable since the header section of the gmail app is always constant. The other locators, on the other hand, are dynamic or cant be used at all. Please check the app and let me know.

Comment: I am not saying don't use xpath, in the right scenario it can be awesome. The use of index looks brittle to me. You don't have to have explicit xpath (ie. You can use "//"). BTW you could use CSS selector to replicate that xpath but that too would be brittle