# What is the equivalent css selector for the xpath : //*[@id='sortable-item_2']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/strong

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have been getting the error while finding element using css selector when I tried to convert the following xpath to its corresponding css.

```
//*[@id='sortable-item_2']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/strong
```

to

```
*[id='sortable-item_2']>div>div[2]>ul>li[1]>a>strong
```

Below is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '*[id='sortable-item_2']>div>div[2]>ul>li[1]>a>strong' is not a valid selector.
>     (Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.146)

Can anyone please help me with the appropriate css selector for the above mentioned xpath

Comment: Your problem is that you are using XPath positions within your CSS selectors. (i.e using `div[2]` is not a valid section for a CSS selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
#sortable-item_2 > div > div:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > strong
```

I suggest not to use such long selectors, you should try to keep it as simple as possible.If you can provide your html code, i can suggest simpler ones.

[Moreover there are ways you can actually verify if a selector returns the element you desire.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203715/gmail-logout-functionality-in-selenium-web-driver/22205277#22205277)

Answer (score 0):

If ID is unique `#sortable-item_2 strong` should be enough then

Comment: If ID is unique then only `#sortable-item_2` is unique. Not any of its descendants, nor the `strong` element in question.